# kafka scripts in "bin" directory fail with "Address already in use" (running in kubernetes)

Tags: kubernetes, kafka

I have a kafka set up running in minikube. It's up and running, and I'm able to produce messages into it and consume them back out.

However, when I'm logging in to one the brokers (using `kubectl exec` if relevant) and try to get some information about its state using one of the scripts in bin, I get an exception `Address already in use`:

```sh
root@kafka-0:/kafka# bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh  --list --bootstrap-server kafka:9092
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:513)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:525)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:461)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:453)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:227)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:80)
    at jdk.httpserver/sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl.bind(ServerImpl.java:134)
    at jdk.httpserver/sun.net.httpserver.HttpServerImpl.bind(HttpServerImpl.java:54)
    at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.client.exporter.HTTPServer.<init>(HTTPServer.java:145)
    at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.jmx.JavaAgent.premain(JavaAgent.java:54)
    ... 6 more
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
Aborted (core dumped)
```

A quick look using `strace` showed that it is trying to bind to port 80. I have no idea why that is even necessary for a script that is meant only to obtain data.

The same error happens on all scripts in the kafka bin directory.

Any ideas regarding on how to fix will be a great help

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, the reason is that JMX exporter will be started under port that already used by Kafka server.

To double-check, you can execute command `ps -ef | grep kafka | grep jmx_prometheus`, then see the result whether it show like this `-javaagent:./jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.1.jar=9083:/usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/prometheus/kafka.yaml`.

It is not like above, please skip my post :), otherwise let's continue

Almost scripts inside "$KAFKA_HOME/bin" will load file "$KAFKA_HOME/conf/kafka-env.sh" and init env variables, one of them is "KAFKA_OPTS" - this option defines JMX port. And then you execute scripts, they will start up javaagent under JMX port ==> raise issue as the below

> Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use

**How to fix:**
I edit a little bit inside code, set `KAFKA_OPTS=""` before executing java command  and it works.

Answer (score 0):

In the command instead of --bootsrap-server can you use --broker-list

Comment: that doesn't help. exact same error

Comment: Just out of curiosity when you write kafka:9092 does it mean hostname of the kafka server is "kafka". If not could you try your original command with IP address instead of hostname

Comment: yes, the hostname is "kafka". kubernetes dns resolves this to the brokers. but for that matter, I already tried using localhost as well

Answer (score 0):

Your `javaagent` is making use of 2 env vars which are conflicting with bin console scripts. Those env vars are `KAFKA_OPTS` and `JMX_PORT`.
What helped for me for confluent container(`confluentinc/cp-server:5.5.1`) is unsetting both of them when entering a running container(via `docker exec`)

```
unset KAFKA_OPTS
unset JMX_PORT
```

This will not impact a running broker because those vars have session scope.